# How to create a 2D drawing board via Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to create an interactive whiteboard for [AltspaceVR](https://developer.altvr.com/). I'm brand new to Three.js and was wondering how to create a 2d canvas that i'm able to draw on. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear. Three.js is for 3D scenes, do you want to create a 2d dashboard inside a 3d scene? You can have only a single canvas at a time, either 2d or 3d, however you could overlay an absolutely positioned div to a 3d scene which would contain your 2d canvas with your dashboard.

You can also use CSS3DObject to embed 2D objects transformed in a 3d scene, here is an [example](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2013/04/30/closing-the-gap-between-html-and-webgl/)